# Unmarking bad block on a drive

Tags: ssd, badblocks

I had gotten root kitted and gone through and zero wiped all my drives. my ssd where I assume had the rootkit installed is reporting a bad block. I went and checked with badblocks and it reported 0 bad blocks. I assume the rootkit just marked it like that to hide itself in that block, however it should be all wiped. whats a good terminal command to unmark that block?

Comment: if badblocks does not show any badblock, then how are you seeing one ? I don't see how the rootkit could be read if it is inside a badblock marked as such by the SSD... And I don't think there is any tool that can revert a badblock at the SSD level. even marking one ?

Comment: well in disk manager the drive is flagged and no recovery disks work citing incorrect memory in the drive, however when I zero wrote to the drive I succesfully managed to fill the full drive including the bad block. bad blocks did not show anything either.